# How to execute code when webpage navigate from one page to another in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, client-side-scripting

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
  HtmlElement from = doc.GetElementById("fromStation");
  HtmlElement to = doc.GetElementById("toStation");
  HtmlElement d = doc.GetElementById("journeyDateInputDate");

  HtmlElement s = doc.GetElementById("ticketType");
  HtmlElement ticket = doc.GetElementById("ticketType");
  HtmlElement submit = doc.GetElementById("jpsubmit");
  HtmlElement hcab = doc.GetElementById("handicapPassengers");

  from.SetAttribute("value", textBox3.Text);
  to.SetAttribute("value", textBox4.Text);
  d.SetAttribute("value", textBox5.Text);
  ticket.SetAttribute("value", Properties.Settings.Default["ticket"].ToString());
  string com = "true";

  if (Properties.Settings.Default["check"].ToString() == com)
    hcab.InvokeMember("click");
  submit.InvokeMember("click");
}
```

I am making project on c#  where i have to execute code when webpage navigate from one page to another and when web load completely.
I have used  button to execute a code when webpage completely loads....but now i what it to execute without using button

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried with a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I think you may need to be a little more descriptive about what your actually trying to achieve, and what you have tried already. That being said it sounds you may need to look at some form of client side language, perhaps JavaScript or jQuery to run once your DOM loads

Comment: I have used button to execute a code when webpage completely loads....but now i what it to execute without using button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*To provide a substantial and correct answer, you might want to provide more specifics on the environment. But assuming a whole bunch of details, I'm making an (un)educated guess here.*

If it's MVC project, you can execute the code as you're presenting the next view. If the page is navigated to from JS (which is on the client) or simply navigated away from your site, it might be much more tricky.

In any case, since it's an operation on the client, you'll need to manage that from JS **on the client**. The server has let the contents go and the page is viewed in the browser even of the server goes down.

```
$(function(){
  alert("Page loaded.");
  // do other stuff
});
```

Comment: I have used button to execute a code when webpage completely loads....but now i what it to execute without using button

Comment: One way to do that is to execute JQuery on load of the page. See my edit.

Comment: @RigzinAngchok If it helped, accept the answer. If there's still something unclear, ask a follow-up in comments, please.